# MVC data access

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm quite new in MVC technology. I have set up my project fine and now i'd like to add some functionalities. I have created and linked a database to my project too.

**Project table**

```
Id, 
Name,
...
```

**Bug table**

```
Project Id,
Name,
...
```

In the index view of my controller I can see the whole list of projects, which are clickable. If I press for example project "TEST", i want to show a new page and show only the bugs which match with the project ID of TEST.

I've been all day with this and can't get it to work. How would you do it?

Comment: If you're new to MVC, you need to follow a basic tutorial to understand the principle and patterns used in it. I recommand the ASP.NET website for that.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Code First or Database First?

Comment: As @Frederick Marcoux recommended, it can be useful a tutorial if you are just starting with MVC. Here is a good one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: you can make an action called BugDetails that takes parameter ProjectId and it returns PartailView the result of db.Bugs.Where(m=> m.ProjectId==ProjectId) and inside your Project view call for @Html.Action("BugDetails","ProjectControllerName",new {ProjectId = Model.Id), if still confused i will provide sample in answer

Comment: @user5135401, your answer would be really appreciated. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Starting from the point that I will assume that you know how to scaffold the CRUD views using MVC.
2. So based on point 1, you have Views [ Create, Edit , List , Details ] for your controller Project [ProjectController]
3. In the controller Project, you can write an action called BugDetails and you call for `@Html.Action("BugDetails,Model.Id)` in the view `Details`

**Inside your Project controller**

```
 public ActionResult BugDetails(int id)
 {
     using(var db = new YourDbContext())
     {
          var bugs = db.Bugs.Where(m=> m.ProjectId == id);
          return PartialView(bugs);
     }
 }
```

**BugDetails.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.Models.Bug>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Bug Name</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach(var bug in Model)
   {
       <tr>
         <td>@bug.Name</td>
       </tr>
   }
</table>
```

**Details.cshtml that is related for Project controller**

```
@model YourProject.Models.Project

//... the details view goes here

@Html.Action("BugDetails","Project",new {id= Model.id}) // Project can be changed depends on how you called your project controller, I assumed that you called it *ProjectController*
```

The above code will render the related bugs in the details view of the project

I hope this will help you

Comment: Finally I got it to work, basically as you mentioned. Now I have another issues..

Comment: @Aldridge1991 like what? better to learn from www.asp.net/mvc , you can start from MVC3  and go upper version step by step

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll assume that you have your clasess like this:

```
public class Project
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...

    public ICollection<Bug> Bugs{ get; set; }
}

public class Bug
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

Then to get the collection of bugs for a gven project:

```
var bugs = _dbContext.Bugs.Where(p => p.ProjectId == id).ToList();
```